# Flash Message is not working in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularJS Flash message to show error messages but getting this error in console. i have tried angularjs previous version too but not able to solve this problem.

```
angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=MainApp&p1=Error%3A…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A274)
at angular.js:38
at angular.js:4458
at n (angular.js:340)
at g (angular.js:4419)
at eb (angular.js:4344)
at c (angular.js:1676)
at yc (angular.js:1697)
at Zd (angular.js:1591)
at angular.js:29013
at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3057)
```

angular code is

```
   var app = angular.module('MainApp',["ngFlash"]);
app.controller('Appctrl',['Flash','$scope','$http',function($scope,$http,Flash) {
  $scope.RegisterUser = function(){
     if($scope.register.username == undefined || $scope.register.email == undefined || $scope.register.password == undefined){
       var message = 'please enter correct information.';
       Flash.create('success', message);
     }
  }
}])
```

html :

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>DNS </title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
  <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <!-- bootstrap link-->
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="/controller/controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="MainApp" ng-controller="Appctrl" >
<div class="container"  >
    <h1><small>Welcome to domains360.net</small></h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <flash-message   duration="5000" show-close="true" on-dismiss="myCallback(flash);" ></flash-message>
  <h3><small>Register here</small></h3>
  <form method="post">
    <label for="name" >User Name</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="register.username" name="username" class="form-control">
    <label for="email" >Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="register.email" class="form-control">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="register.password" class="form-control"/>
    <input type="button" ng-click="RegisterUser();" class="form-control btn btn-success"   value="Sign up">
  </form>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h3><small>Login Here</small></h3>
  <form method="post" action="/user/authenticate">
    <label for="email" >Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control"/>
    <div class="alert-danger"><%=messages%></div>
    <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-success "  value="Sign In">
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Where i am getting error or where i am wrong please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: it doesn't look like you have the `<script>` for `angular-flash` included in your HTML.  However, the answer @Vivz posted is also a problem which will happen after you fix your script tags....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you are missing the reference for angular-flash . Also after injecting make sure you are injecting parameters in the correct order as follows,

```
app.controller('Appctrl',['$scope','$http','Flash',function($scope,$http,Flash) {
```

Comment: Reference for angular-flash??

Comment: @sachinyadav https://github.com/sachinchoolur/angular-flash/blob/master/dist/angular-flash.js

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the plugin to use its features. For more info https://github.com/sachinchoolur/angular-flash. Additionally change the order in your controller

```
app.controller('Appctrl',['Flash','$scope','$http',function(Flash,$scope,$http) {
  $scope.RegisterUser = function(){
     if($scope.register.username == undefined || $scope.register.email == undefined || $scope.register.password == undefined){
       var message = 'please enter correct information.';
       Flash.create('success', message);
     }
  }
}])
```